# What is difference between the result of using GPU or not?

Tags: python-3.x, keras, gpu, conv-neural-network

I have a CNN with 2 hidden layers. When i use keras on cpu with 8GB RAM, sometimes i have "Memory Error" or sometimes precision class was 0 but some classes at the same time were 1.00. If i use keras on GPU,will it solve my problem?

Comment: Do you mean "it solved !!!" or "will it solve???" --- 8GB is little ram, it's easy to blow it with models. If you have a GPU, the model will need to fit inside the GPU RAM, so it depends on the size of your GPU. You may get extra space because your data will be at CPU RAM, while training will happen at GPU RAM, this divides the space you occupy. --- The only certain thing is: you will gain A LOT of speed with GPU.

Comment: Hi. Thanks. I'm using cpu. if i am using GPU, the precision of each class will raising or it's not depend on run on cpu or gpu?

Comment: It should not change. Only speed should have a significant change.

Comment: In this link, https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/19200, difference between result of train on cpu and gpu is shown.

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't have enough memory to fit all the images in the CPU during training. Using a GPU will only help if it has more memory. If this is happening because you have too many images or they're resolution is too high, you can try using keras' ImageDataGenerator and any of the flow methods to feed your data in batches.